# How can I convert array into object $user['name'] >>>> $user->name?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any laravel solution? Collection is not working. Symfony would work too.

```
    $a = User::all(); //Eloquent Collection <-- i want my method to return this

    $users = User::rating();  //Eloquent Collection <-- i want my method to return Eloquent Collection

    return $users; // array
```

Here is my method:

```
    public static function rating() : array {

    $arr = [];

    $data = static::calculateRating() //array;
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $user = static::with("reviews")->find($item->id);
        $user = collect($user);
        $user->put("rating", (int)$item->rate_sum);
        $arr[] = $user;
    }

    return $arr;

}
```

So I could use this `$user->name` instead of `$user['name']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the cast operator

```
$userObject = (object) $user;
```

as specified here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

> An array converts to an object with properties named by keys and corresponding values, with the exception of numeric keys which will be inaccessible unless iterated

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
$user = json_decode(json_encode($user));
```